# while loop with conditions

Tags: r, foreach, while-loop

I have been trying to compute a bigger function and one part of it is a while loop with 2 conditions. Foreach value of k, in a certain range of values (x_min and x_max are computed within the whole function), i am trying to compute a matrix with values from a distribution in which the k itself is a part. The while loop assesses that the necessary conditions for the distribution are met, while the foreach- function should compute the while loop for every element of k. Since i do not know the exact amount of elements in k, i thought the problem might be the predetermination of I. The best i could derive was an endless computation within the loops (or simple crashes of R). I am thankful for any suggestion!

```
I<-mat.or.vec(n,10000)
  k<-x[x_min < x & x < x_max]
  foreach(k) %do% { 
    for(i in 1:100){
      check=0
      while(check==0){
      I<-replicate(n=100,rbinom(n= 250, size=1, prob = k/250))
      if(sum(I[,i])==k) check=1
      } 
    }
  }
```

Changing the order unfortunatly did not work.
It seems to still have problems. I tried to extract the matrix, but it is reporting "NULL".

n is 250, x_min and x_max are defined from a formula (around 2-8), k is defined within the formula given above, x are values between 0 and around 10 (also computed within the formula). I would provide you with the whole formula, but it is big and i could narrow down the problems to these parts, so i wanted to keep the problem as simple as possible. Thank you for your help and comments!

Comment: I think you should put the `check=0` outside the `for` loop, and after the `foreach(k) %do% {`

Comment: Unfortunatly, it did not work as i wished. Sorry for the false report.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide values for `n`, `x_min`, `x_max`, and `x`